# Website animations lag on retina/higher resolution Macbook display but smooth on lower resolutions

Tags: reactjs, web, screen-resolution, web-animations

We built website on React. Flawless on chrome, android and iPhones but Animations lag on safari macbook pro 16" default resolution 1792 x 1120.

Website works amazing if display setting is one knotch down at 1650x1050.

[Display setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcoHL.png)

Is there a way to target/or write CSS to bring resolutions down?

Answer (score -1):

You should try using a different browser or it might be a computer performance issue.

There could be something in your code that causes it to lag.

I am not a mac user so this might not be the perfect answer.